# Why may I keep getting "Expected RBRACE" where one isn't needed?

Tags: css

I am currently creating variables for color codes in css but I keep getting an error saying "Expected RBRACE" but one is not needed where it says to put it. I am working in dreamweaver so I'm not sure if this is just an issue with it or not. The error is showing for lines 4,5,9,10 specifically where it says "--primarycolor" and "--secondarycolor". It wants me to put a right bracket right before it.

```css
@charset "utf-8";

:root {
    --primarycolor: #edf2fc;
    --secondarycolor: #212121;
}

.dark-theme {
    --primarycolor: #212121;
    --secondarycolor: #edf2fc;
}

#toggler {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: dodgerblue;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 20px;
    color: var(--secondary-color);
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#toggler:active {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: blue;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 20px;
    color: var(--secondary-color);
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 15px;
}

body {
    background-color: var(--primary-color);
}

h1 {
    color: var(--secondary-color);
}
```

Comment: https://community.adobe.com/t5/dreamweaver-discussions/css-variable/m-p/10146143

Comment: Thank you. Sucks they don't support it. Guess I'll have to switch programs.